# document.getElementById('button2').click(); not working

Tags: javascript

I am try to automatically fire a sub routine with with a javascript "document.getElementById('button2').click();" as it is in the below code. Can someone please help me see why the  code is not working. Thank you

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="iso-8859-1" debug = "true"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data"%>
<script language="vb" runat="server">
Sub sendmsg(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
response.Redirect("index.aspx")
End Sub
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function Confirm() {
    var str = $('#loutput').val(); //'We are inviting you for s special business meeting on Tueday, at No 12, Fred street. for more information please call 02341123333';

    var updateString = function(input_text) {
        //1. Find consecutive 11 numeric digits
        var match = input_text.match(/\d{11}/);
        //2. divide it into a string of 3s separated by space
        var new_str = '';
        for (var i = 1; i < match[0].length + 1; i++) {
            new_str = new_str + match[0][i - 1];
            if (i > 1 && i % 3 == 0)
                new_str = new_str + ' ';
        }
        //3. Replace old match no. with the new one
        console.log(match)
        if (match[0] != '')
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Message contains numeric characters which might make the message not delivered to some networks. Do you want us to reformat the message ?. This might increase the numbers of pages of the message and the cost?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            input_text = input_text.replace(match[0], new_str)
            $('#loutput').val(input_text);
            confirm2()

            //document.getElementById('loutput').innerHTML = input_text;

        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
            confirm2()
        }
        $('#loutput').val(input_text);
        //document.getElementById('loutput').innerHTML = input_text;
    };
    updateString(str);
};

function confirm2() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm(" send the message now?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        document.getElementById('button2').click();

        //document.getElementById('loutput').innerHTML = input_text;

    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }

    //document.getElementById('loutput').innerHTML = input_text;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<form runat="server" action="formatmessage3.aspx" method="post">
<input type="texarea" id="loutput" name="loutput" value="<%=request.form ("loutput") %>" />
<button ID="button1" OnClick="Confirm();" runat="server">Confirm</button>
<asp:button ID="button2" OnClick="sendmsg" Text="send" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is horrible looking javascript. Your functions are in global scope as well which is pretty bad.

Comment: @Magrangs Your comment is kind of rude and there is nothing wrong with functions in global scope.

Comment: @A1rPun "nothing wrong with functions in global scope" - yes there is. Plenty wrong with it. if you have a user control on that page that declares a function called 'Confirm' it will be overwritten, also the same for imported 3rd party libraries. the code is littered with comments which are unnecessary, just refactor to a meaningful function and there is commented out code which is also bad practice. The functions are also difficult to read and understand, so yes IMO it is horrible JS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the fact you are using a .NET button with runat="server" so it is going to change the id of the button to a different value.

```
<asp:button ID="button2" OnClick="sendmsg" Text="send" runat="server" />
```

You either have to reference the element by a class

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].click();
```

or reference the dynamic name

```
document.getElementById("<%= button2.ClientID %>").click();
```

or in .NET4 you can use `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: referenced the dynamic name as suggested by replacing  document.getElementById('button2').click();
 with document.getElementById("<%= button2.ClientID %>").click(); but it is still not working

Comment: So what is the error message in the browser's console?

Comment: Okay so it can not find the button. Look at the source code and see what the script is referencing and what the id of the button actually is.

Comment: i have looked through, the button id is button2 and document.getElementById("<%= button2.ClientID %>").click();  is used