# Sweet Alert Response Call Server Function in JavaScript on ASP Webform

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, sweetalert

I want to call server side function based on user response on sweetalert in my javascript function. I tried using non ajax function, with 2 buttons solution. One button to show sweet alert and second button called inside sweet alert.

HTML Code (2 button) :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="DelUser" Text="" style="display:none;" OnClick="DeleteEvent"/>
<asp:Button ID="DeleteUser" runat="server" Text="Delete User" Width="122px" BackColor="#FF572D" Font-Bold="True"  OnClick="DeleteUser_Click" />
```

JS Function and sweetalert source :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert@2.1.2/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">

function delalert() {
   
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Are you sure that you want to delete this data?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons:true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
        .then(willDelete => {
            if (willDelete) {
                document.getElementById("DelUser").click();

            }
            else {
                swal("Safe!", "Your imaginary file is safe!", "success");
            }
        });
  
}
```

And in my server side code (aspx.cs):

```
       protected void DeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "delalert()", true);
       
    }

    protected void DeleteEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("ASSSSSDASDASDASDSDSD");
    }
```

Else function works just fine but when i click ok it shows nothing, the DeleteEvent not called. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks ok, except for the hidden button selector. Just add the tag ClientIDMode="static".

Or, you can of course use this:

```
getElementById('<%= DelUser.ClientID %>');
```

However, you have this backwards. The user does not click on server button, and THEN you in code behind attempt to inject + run the js dialog box.

You don't need that part in your code behind - REMOVE the script register.

However, there is a NICE trick you can use here, and thus only need ONE button.

And BETTER YET you don't have hard code the button. So, in theory, you could make a general routine and even one that you trigger from code behind. (but, you would have to pass the button to click as part of that setup). but, lets deal with one issue at a time here.

As we know, most jQuery/js dialog boxes of course don't wait. So, then you can't really return true/false, since the js code runs, and returns the value and THEN pops up the dialog box. So, a common solution is of course your duel button, and the hidden button trick.

However, you can actually make this work with JUST one button, and not really much of any code change here. And as noted, bonus points, since this also lets you use/get/pass the location of the button click.

so, assume this button click:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="31px" Text="Button" Width="159px"
            OnClientClick="return delalert(this);"                
            OnClick="Button1_Click"    />
```

Note how I do NOT hide the button. You ONLY need the one button.

But, your alert code now becomes this:

```
    <script>
        var delalertok = false
        function delalert(btn) {

            if (delalertok) {
                delalertok = false
                return true
            }
            
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Are you sure that you want to delete this data?",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
            })
                .then(willDelete => {
                    if (willDelete) {
                        delalertok = true;
                        btn.click();
                    }
                    else {
                        swal("Safe!", "Your imaginary file is safe!", "success");
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }

    </script>
```

Note how we added a global delalertok. The initialization of js code ONLY runs the first time on page load. So, we set that value = false.

Note how we passed the button - so we don't need to change the alert code for different buttons on the same page.

Note also how the last line of the routine returns false.

Note also how by passing the button, we can "click" it again.

So, you click on your button. js code runs, pops dialog - returns false. Server side button did not run.

Note the dialog is popped up. If user hits ok, then your code stub runs, clicks the button, but BEFORE we click, we set that value = true. So now the click button runs again, it sees true in the first lines of the jscode, and thus your button will "now" get a return true - and will run the server side event.

We thus do not need nor require any server side register script here.

Comment: I already tried your code, but I think there's problem in my OnClientClick method. It shows the alert like a flash then go closed in an instant. There's a solution which take the states of view(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227386/sweet-alert-confirm-dialog-in-asp-net). But I guess I will take the simplest solution here. Thankyou.

Comment: If it goes away like that then a post back is occurring - suggests a  code error in the script. Create a test page - drop in one button, try it. You are missing something here. Note how the function passes this (the button). Thus no getelement is required

Comment: My above code approach works - been used for years. Are you sure you pass "this" in the oncliientClick event?

Comment: My mistake forget to put return false in the end, but i notice there's no function or command to trigger the deleteevent on server side.

Comment: You are correct. I did not put in the server side event since code was to show  post-back does not occur if you cancel. With above code, note the post-back if you hit ok, but none if you don't. Did not bother to add the server side event, that of course for you to do! As noted, the simple layout and simple code is how to do this. Posted code works. Even without the server side event, you note that cancel does not cause a post-back, but ok does - and that's all you need to be up and running and off to the races for this to work. I suppose for history and readers I put in a onclick markup.

Comment: Ok, I have put in the onclick for the button markup. it does not change that what was posted works fine. However, for the sake of clarity, and for those that don't realize that code snips posted are often air code, then I added the onclick markup. I kind of thought that the requirement to add a server side click event was going to be something readers realize they will have to do like for all buttons - but I suppose that's a bit too much to ask of readers to realize that for a server side button event code, they will and do have to put in a server side event. So good idea - and done!

Comment: Also, since this answer works - might want to mark this as a answer - kind of a common curtesy on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer I found here :
[Link for Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893210/document-getelementbyidbutton2-click-not-working)

The problem seems on my

```
document.getElementById("DelUser").click();
```

And the HTML I'm referencing at.
So the solution would be :

1. Reference the dynamic name

   `document.getElementById("<%= DelUser.ClientID %>").click();`
2. In .NET4 we can use `ClientIDMode="Static"`

The HTML Code then becomes :

`<asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="DelUser" Text="" style="display:none;" OnClick="DeleteEvent"/>`

And called like previous method :
`document.getElementById("DelUser").click();`

Either way it will work just fine.